# Почему css файл упорно не хочет видеть и выводить изображения из папки images в HTML страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Объясните пжл мальцу(всего 5 дней как ололопрограмист) что я делаю не так ?
CSS файл выводит параметры такие как высота и ширина но не делает фон кнопки из изображения, причем я так же мучился и с фоном самой страницы. Пытался вызвать фон из css файла, после пару часов недоумевай что не так, просто залил его в head через body( но сомневаюсь что это правильно). HTML файл находится в той-же директории что и папки images и styles. Имя изображения верное.[image: пример]

```css
.button1 {
  background-image: url('images/Rey.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Relic Calculator</title>
  <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    body {
      background-image: url('images/Background.jpg');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; height:100vh;">
    <button class="button1">Button 1</button>
    <button class="button2">Button 2</button>
    <button class="button3">Button 3</button>
    <button class="button4">Button 4</button>
    <button class="button5">Button 5</button>
    <button class="button6">Button 6</button>
    <button class="button7">Button 7</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ну если стили и изображения в отдельных папках, то путь к изображению в CSS файле должен быть чем-то вроде `background-image: url('../images/Rey.png');`. Все зависит от структуры директорий. В HTML файле это `background-image: url('images/Background.jpg');` сработало, так как файл на том же уровне что и директория с изображениями.

Comment: В папке GoH лежат Html файл и 2 папки - styles( с css файлом) и images( с изображениями). Какой должен быть путь если они в общей папке GoH ? или надо блин полностью указывать  тип : рабочий стол/GoH/images/Rey.png ?

Comment: Я же Вам выше написал. Я понял что HTML файл находится в некой папке в корне, рядом с HTML файлом лежит папка со стилями и с изображениями. [Quick Reminder About File Paths](https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

Comment: `background-image: url('/images/Rey.png');` в файле styles.css

Comment: Ухты... ну вы шайтаны, кудесники, изобретатели, спасибо за ссылку и объяснение !!!. заработало через ../